# TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress is not firing

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I have am making a form in React Native (testing on IOS/Expo go) and for reasons that I cannot pinpoint, my TouchableWithoutFeedback's onPress event is not firing at all.

I made sure to wrap the TouchableWithoutFeedback's children in a single View component (as suggested by other answers on github and stack overflow), but the problem persists.

```
import React from 'react';
import {TouchableWithoutFeedback, Dimensions, StyleSheet, ScrollView, Keyboard, Text, View, Image, SafeAreaView, Button , Pressable, TextInput, FlatList} from 'react-native';
import Header from './Header';
import { createNativeStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import { useNavigation, useRoute } from '@react-navigation/native';
import DateTimePickerModal from 'react-native-modal-datetime-picker';
import constants from './constants';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Feather';


export default function NewMemory(){

    const [dateShow, setDateShow] = React.useState(false);
    const [timeShow, setTimeShow] = React.useState(false);

    const [date, setDate] = React.useState('');
    const [time, setTime] = React.useState('');

    function setDateWrapper(date){
        console.log(date.toLocaleDateString());
        setDate(date.toLocaleDateString());
        setDateShow(false);
    }

    function setTimeWrapper(time){
        time = time.toLocaleTimeString();
        let tokens = time.split(':');
        let ampm = tokens[tokens.length-1];
        ampm = ampm.split(' ')[1];
        tokens[2] = ampm;
        setTime(tokens[0] + ':' + tokens[1] + ' ' + ampm);
        setTimeShow(false);
    }

    return (
        
        <View style={{width: '100%', /* borderColor:'green', borderWidth: 1 */}}>
            
            <Header title='Send Capsule' backButton></Header>
            <View style={{borderBottomColor:'grey', borderBottomWidth:1, display:'flex', flexDirection:'row', padding: 10}}>
                <Icon name='image' size={70}></Icon>

                
                <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={()=> {console.log('this message should appear on screen tap, but doesnt'); Keyboard.dismiss()}}>
                <View style={{flex: 1, borderWidth: 3, borderColor: 'red'}}>
                    <TextInput 
                        
                        multiline 
                        placeholder='Write a caption...' 
                        style={{ flex: 1, padding:10, paddingTop: 12, paddingBottom: 12}}
                        maxHeight={240}
                    ></TextInput>
                </View>
                </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                

            </View>

            <View style={{ padding: 10}}>

                <View>
                    <Text style={{marginBottom:5}}>Unlock Date</Text>
                    <Pressable onPress={()=>setDateShow(true)} style={{display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row', alignItems:'center', padding: 10,  borderRadius:5, backgroundColor: constants.inputFieldGreyBackground}}>
                        <Text style={date? null : {color: '#b5b5b5'}}>{date ? date : 'Date'}</Text>
                    </Pressable>
                </View>

                <View style={{height:10}}></View>
                
                
                <Pressable onPress={()=>setTimeShow(true)} style={{display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row', alignItems:'center', padding: 10,  borderRadius:5, backgroundColor: constants.inputFieldGreyBackground}}>
                    <Text style={time? null : {color: '#b5b5b5'}}>{time ? time : 'Time (optional)'}</Text>
                </Pressable>
     
                
                
                <DateTimePickerModal isVisible={dateShow} display='spinner' mode='date' onCancel={()=>setDateShow(false)} onConfirm={(date)=> {setDateWrapper(date)}}></DateTimePickerModal>
                <DateTimePickerModal isVisible={timeShow} display='spinner' mode='time' onCancel={()=>setTimeShow(false)} onConfirm={(time)=> {setTimeWrapper(time)}}></DateTimePickerModal>

            </View>

            
        </View>
      
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason why you must use "ToucheableWithoutFeedback"? I'd recommend you to use "Pressable" instead as suggested by [official React Native docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/touchablewithoutfeedback) on ToucheableWithoutFeedback.

React Native official documentation on ToucheableWithoutFeedback:

> Do not use unless you have a very good reason.

---

There's two ways you can fix the issue.

### **1. Continue using ToucheableWithoutFeedback**

You'll have to follow the documentation on how it should be used.

Note that you need to add `{...props}` in the `<View />` component.

> Importantly, TouchableWithoutFeedback works by cloning its child and
> applying responder props to it. It is therefore required that any
> intermediary components pass through those props to the underlying
> React Native component. (From react native docs)

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={()=> {console.log('hello'); Keyboard.dismiss()}}>
  <View {...props} style={{flex: 1, borderWidth: 3, borderColor: 'red'}}>
    <TextInput            
      multiline 
      placeholder='Write a caption...' 
      style={{ flex: 1, padding:10, paddingTop: 12, paddingBottom: 12}}
      maxHeight={240}
    />
  </View>              
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

### **2. Change ToucheableWithoutFeedback to Pressable.**

Note that you don't need to pass `{...props}`.

```
<Pressable onPress={()=> {console.log('hello'); Keyboard.dismiss()}}>
  <View style={{flex: 1, borderWidth: 3, borderColor: 'red'}}>
    <TextInput            
      multiline 
      placeholder='Write a caption...' 
      style={{ flex: 1, padding:10, paddingTop: 12, paddingBottom: 12}}
      maxHeight={240}
    />
  </View>              
</Pressable>
```

Comment: I ended up using pressable, touchableWithoutFeedback was the most common answer I found online but it wasn't necessary. Thank you

Comment: Please accept it as the answer if it helped! It can help improve the community and cause less confusion by promoting the usage of Pressable over ToucheableWithoutFeedback.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
import React from 'react';
    import {TouchableWithoutFeedback, Dimensions, StyleSheet, ScrollView, Keyboard, Text, View, Image, SafeAreaView, Button , Pressable, TextInput, FlatList,} from 'react-native';
    import { createNativeStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
    import { useNavigation, useRoute } from '@react-navigation/native';
    import DateTimePickerModal from 'react-native-modal-datetime-picker';
    import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Feather';
    
    
    export default function App(){
    
        const [dateShow, setDateShow] = React.useState(false);
        const [timeShow, setTimeShow] = React.useState(false);
    
        const [date, setDate] = React.useState('');
        const [time, setTime] = React.useState('');
    
        function setDateWrapper(date){
            console.log(date.toLocaleDateString());
            setDate(date.toLocaleDateString());
            setDateShow(false);
        }
    
        function setTimeWrapper(time){
            time = time.toLocaleTimeString();
            let tokens = time.split(':');
            let ampm = tokens[tokens.length-1];
            ampm = ampm.split(' ')[1];
            tokens[2] = ampm;
            setTime(tokens[0] + ':' + tokens[1] + ' ' + ampm);
            setTimeShow(false);
        }
    
        return (
            
            <View style={{width: '100%', /* borderColor:'green', borderWidth: 1 */}}>
                
                <View style={{borderBottomColor:'grey', borderBottomWidth:1, display:'flex', flexDirection:'row', padding: 10}}>
                    <Icon name='image' size={70}></Icon>
    
                    
                    <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={()=> {console.log('hello'); Keyboard.dismiss()}}>
                     <View style={{flex: 1, borderWidth: 3, borderColor: 'red'}}>
                        <TextInput 
                            
                            multiline 
                            placeholder='Write a caption...' 
                            style={{ flex: 1, padding:10, paddingTop: 12, paddingBottom: 12}}
                            maxHeight={240}
                        ></TextInput>
                    </View>
                 
                    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                    
    
                </View>
    
                <View style={{ padding: 10}}>
    
                    <View>
                        <Text style={{marginBottom:5}}>Unlock Date</Text>
                        <Pressable onPress={()=>setDateShow(true)} style={{display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row', alignItems:'center', padding: 10,  borderRadius:5, }}>
                            <Text style={date? null : {color: '#b5b5b5'}}>{date ? date : 'Date'}</Text>
                        </Pressable>
                    </View>
    
                    <View style={{height:10}}></View>
                    
                    
                    <Pressable onPress={()=>setTimeShow(true)} style={{display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row', alignItems:'center', padding: 10,  borderRadius:5, }}>
                        <Text style={time? null : {color: '#b5b5b5'}}>{time ? time : 'Time (optional)'}</Text>
                    </Pressable>
         
                    
                    
                    <DateTimePickerModal isVisible={dateShow} display='spinner' mode='date' onCancel={()=>setDateShow(false)} onConfirm={(date)=> {setDateWrapper(date)}}></DateTimePickerModal>
                    <DateTimePickerModal isVisible={timeShow} display='spinner' mode='time' onCancel={()=>setTimeShow(false)} onConfirm={(time)=> {setTimeWrapper(time)}}></DateTimePickerModal>
    
                </View>
    
                
            </View>
          
        );
    }
```

Comment: Do you get the same output when running on IOS device?

Comment: is there specific reason to use TouchableWithoutFeedback instead of TouchableOpacity